# React Native Device Can Call

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Is it possible to determine the possibility of a device to make a call?
I need to determine the ability of the device to call. Depending on whether it can or not, I have to render two different components. In the first case it will be a button that will open the phone window. In the second case it will be just a component that displays the phone number.

Option with `Linking.canOpenURL('tel:+1 555 555 5555')` is not working for me.

Comment: What happens when you try `Linking.canOpenURL`?

Comment: @jevakallio It return's true for tablet device that can't actually call